# Exercise 1.3.7 in Grimmett & Stirzaker's 'Probability and Random Processes'

Tags: probability-theory

I'm having trouble solving exercise 1.3.7 (and even understanding the solution) from Grimmett & Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes*, which reads:

> You are given that at least one, but no more than three, of the events $A_r$, $1 \le r \le n$, occur, where $n \ge 3$. The probability of atleast two occurring is $1/2$. If P$(A_r)$ = $p$, P$(A_r \cap A_s)$ = $q$, $r \ne s$ and P$(A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t) = x$, $r \lt s \lt t$ show that $p \ge 3/(2n)$, and $q \le 4/n$.

I'm linking the solution to the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbC6I.jpg). I am not able to understand what the *ﬁrst three terms in the latter series* (in the solution) are and how they lead to the final equation.

The second term in the series seems to be the intersection of all the 2-pairs according to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feedback from Lord Shark the Unknown helped but the following way of counting drove the point across:

For the **second term** in the sequence, we are essentially choosing 3 numbers (a,b,c) in $n\choose{3}$ for $$A_{r,s} \cap A_{t,u} = A_a \cap A_b \cap A_c$$ such that $$a \lt b \lt c \\ r \lt s, t \lt u \\ (r,s) \ne (t,u)$$.
Now, given the constraints, the following 3 can be the possible orderings of a,b,c:
$$\{\{(a,b),(b,c)\},\{(a,b),(a,c)\},\{(a,c),(b,c)\}\}$$

For the **third term**, we still have to choose 3 distinct numbers (a,b,c) in $n\choose{3}$ ways, but now $$A_{r,s} \cap A_{t,u} \cap A_{v,w} = A_a \cap A_b \cap A_c$$ such that $$a \lt b \lt c \\ r \lt s, t \lt u, v \lt w \\ (r,s) \ne (t,u) \ne (v,w)$$
Now, given the constraints, only the following can be the possible ordering of a,b,c:
$$\{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$$

Therefore, the second term contributes $3 {n\choose{3}}$ and the third term contributes ${n\choose{3}}$.

Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the inclusion-exclusion principle. The linked solution
applies it to the events $A_{r,s}=A_r\cap A_s$. The solution displays
these events and their double intersections $A_{r,s}\cap A_{t,u}$.
The third term is the sum of their triple intersections. One gets
nonzero contributions from triple intersections like
$$A_{r,s}\cap A_{r,t}\cap A_{s,t}=A_r\cap A_s\cap A_t.$$
There are $\binom{n}3$ of these. But the other terms  in this
 sum involve triple intersections which equal the intersection of
four or more of the $A_i$, so their probability is zero.

Likewise in the second sum, only intersections like $A_{r,s}\cap A_{r,t}$
count.